# System.StringException: Invalid regex: Illegal repetition {![a-zA-Z0-9_.]*}

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

`{![a-zA-Z0-9_.]*}` is not working when I use it as a regex in Apex:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile('{![a-zA-Z0-9_.]*}'); 
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher('{!Account.Name}');
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Where is it located formula or apex?

Comment: Apex :: Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile('{![a-zA-Z0-9_.]*}');
    Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher('{!Account.Name}');

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile('\\{![a-zA-Z0-9_.]*\\}'); 
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher('{!Account.Name}');
system.debug(matcher.find());
```

The curly braces are used to group parts of a regex together to express repetition. So, to find curly braces, you need to escape them with `\\`

Answer (score 1):

If your pattern is the correct one you want to use then looks like where is extra "{!" and "}". 
It should looks like:

```
 Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*'); 
 Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher('{!Account.Name}');
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Not Working ...

Comment: I have answered to your question correctly since where are extra "{!" and "}" which must be removed. Looks like the pattern is not correct one which you want to use. I suggest you fix your regex pattern. Here are examples of the patterns: http://wiki.tcl.tk/989 also you can test your pattern here: https://regex101.com/